# jQuery Ajax load many of the same things

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've got an ajax request that returns a bunch of URLs and I created images like

```
<img URL="1" />
<img URL="1" />
<img URL="2" />
<img URL="1" />
<img URL="3" />
<img URL="2" />
```

etc...

I need to store them as URL="1" because I need to make a separate ajax request to getURLfromID which I feed in "1" and on success it will return filepath "folder/folder/image.jpg", which I then assign to the correct img tag

The issue is if I have 1000 imgs with URL="1", it will make 1000 requests to getURLfromID("1") before a response from one of them is obtained

EDIT: URL="x" will always give the same filepath for the same URL value

Is there a way for me to do

```
var URLs = {}
function setURL(imgObj, URL) {
    if(URL not in URLs) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "getURLfromID",
            data: {url: URL},
            success: function(filePath) {
                URLs[URL] = filePath
                $(imgObj).attr("src", filePath)
            }
        })
    } else {
        wait for URLs[URL] to obtain a value...
        $(imgObj).attr("src", URLs[URL])
    }
}
```

specifically the last bit in else, where it waits until one ajax has made a request, then can assign all the img tags' attr to the same src

Note: When I open console=>network I see xhr requests for the same URL be made tonnes of times (disable-cache is not ticked)

Comment: under URL="1" is same filepath?

Comment: yes, all the same URLs are the same filepath

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(function() {
  $('img[URL="1"]').each(function () {   
    $(this).attr('src','newurl');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Blesson, I took your idea and this is what I did

```
var setImageAjax = [];
var setImageObjects = [];
// Sets  image to the image of the id attr
function setImage(imageObj, id) {
    if(!$(imageObj).attr("src")) {
        if (!(id in setImageObjects)) {
            setImageObjects[id] = new Array()
        }
        if (!(id in setImageAjax)) {
            setImageAjax[id] = false;
        } else if (setImageAjax[id] != false && setImageAjax[id] != true) {
            $(imageObj).attr("src", setImageAjax[id]);
            return
        }
        if (setImageAjax[id] == false) {
           setImageAjax[id] = true
           $.ajax({
                url: "urlurlurl",
                method: "GET",
                data: {
                    id: id
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    setImageAjax[id] = data;
                    while(setImageObjects[id].length) {
                        $(setImageObjects[id].pop()).attr("src", data);
                    }
                }
           })
        } else {
            setImageObjects[id].push(imageObj);
        }

    }
}
```